# Close Multiple Buffers Programatically in Vim

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm trying to write a function that allows me to toggle TPope's Vim Fugitive git-log viewer.

The plugin allows you to view the history of your project, by opening up git objects as buffers that begin with `fugitive://`

I'm trying to write a function in vimscript that will allow me to close all of these buffers at once, when they're open. The function currently looks like this, and is quite close to working:

```
function! ToggleGLog()
    if buflisted(bufname('fugitive'))
      :cclose
      :bd fugitive*<C-a><cr>
    else
        Glog
    endif
endfunction
command! ToggleGLog :silent :call ToggleGLog()
nnoremap <silent> <leader>gl :ToggleGLog<CR>
```

The problem that I'm encountering is that the `<C-a><cr>` portion of the function doesn't work. Normally, the `<C-a>` would expand the `*` selector to match all the buffers that start with "fugitive."

How can I write this so that the names of those buffers are automatically expanded and the `:bd` command will close them all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following?

```
execute "normal! :bdelete fugitive*\<C-a>\<CR>"
```

`normal` lets Vim run the command to its right as if you typed it, including keys like `<C-a>`. But as the latter is somewhat special, it needs to be *interpreted*; this is what `execute` is doing here. (See the end part of `:help normal`.)